# Original error: Could not find 'aapt.exe'

Tags: appium-android, aapt

I am having hte below error when i try to open an app using appium

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new
>   remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original
>   error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the
>   command. Original error: Could not find 'aapt.exe' in
>   ["C:\Users\nsingh163\Desktop\Naresh Folder\Automation\Mobile
>   Automation\Downloads\Android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe","C:\Users\nsingh163\Desktop\Naresh Folder\Automation\Mobile
>   Automation\Downloads\Android-sdk\emulator\aapt.exe","C:\Users\nsingh163\Desktop\Naresh
>   Folder\Automation\Mobile
>   Automation\Downloads\Android-sdk\tools\aapt.exe","C:\Users\nsingh163\Desktop\Naresh
>   Folder\Automation\Mobile
>   Automation\Downloads\Android-sdk\tools\bin\aapt.exe"]. Do you
>   have Android Build Tools installed at
>   'C:\Users\nsingh163\Desktop\Naresh Folder\Automation\Mobile
>   Automation\Downloads\Android-sdk'? Build info: version: '3.141.59',
>   revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host:
>   'USD4FWTN2', ip: '10.88.4.6', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64',
>   os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171' Driver info:
>   driver.version: AndroidDriver

I have tried installing Android SDK again but still not able to find aapt.exe in hte tools folder

Answer (score 3):

I am quite new to the mobile automation but I encountered this issue and how I managed to fix it...

aapt.exe is actually not in the "tools" folder :), you have to get "build-tools" folder and there you can find it

in cmd or whatever you are using, you can enter this command (bare in mind that the version is just as an example, I think that it has to match platform-tools you installed previously)

```
sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.0"
```

So, once you have the build-tools folder, just go there and copy aapt.exe from there to the "tools" folder

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, below are the steps:
1. Find API level for your phone/ device. Setting -> About device -> Software Info -> Note down Android Version. -> Goto https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history
from here, find out API Level for your Android Version.
2. Navigate to sdkmanager.bat path in CMD (\sdk-tools-windows-4333796\tools\bin) and use "sdkmanager "build-tools;21.0.0" to download build-tools for API level 21, change it as per your API level.
3. Once done, copy aapt.exe file from build-tools folder to platform-tools folder.

This should resolve the issue.